# Menu link in adminhtml, ::before pseudoelement before my link

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, magento-2.1

[image]

As you can see from the image, recently a new ::before pseudoelement started appearing near my module link in the admin and I cannot find out where it is being pulled from.

Inspect element:
[image]
[image]

The module is quite large, so I'm inserting only the menu.xml. But please tell me **where to look for possible causes**. This wasn't appearing at the beginning, although if I checkout any of my previous commits it still appears. I don't load any css in my module. Cleared cache, recompiled:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::model"
             title="Module"
             module="Vendor_Module"
             sortOrder="9999"
             resource="Vendor_Module::model" 
             parent="Magento_Backend::content"
             action="module/model"
            />                            
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Even though the title may imply it's not a duplicate the answer will explain in details how to find out how those content CSS properties are created

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism thanks Raphael. will take a look

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by removing `stores` keyword from my id in `menu.xml`. It seems that whenever you add some words that are used by magento you will a certain class.

```
 <add id="Vendor_Module::stores"
```

became

```
 <add id="Vendor_Module"
```